# Putting prior on a function of parameters

Tags: bayesian, estimation, prior

Suppose that we have a likelihood for a conditional distribution $p(y|X,\theta)$. For clarity purposes we can consider linear regression with homescadastic errors. It is clear to me how one will put a prior on the parameters, i.e. $\pi(\theta)$.

Instead of doing that can we put a prior $\pi(\mu)$ over $\mu = g(X,\theta)$ where $g$ is an inverse link function for the mean of $p(y|\mu)$ and estimate $\theta$? Does it make sense? Is there a name for this procedure?

Comment: Maybe the g-prior is what you are looking for? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-prior

Comment: @hejseb - no, the g-prior is effectively over different models, not over a function of the parameters.  An example of this question (it seems to me) could be "can I put a prior on $\mu^2$ instead of directly on $\mu$?  How?", which is different than "How can I put a prior on some regression coefficients being identically equal to zero?"

Comment: @jbowman Yes, you are right - I was thinking mostly about using $X$.

Answer (score 4):

Another perspective on this: Yes, of course you can do that, the only question in practice is how you do it.

There's several options:

- You can work out the changes in variables etc. and explicitly define the implied priors on the untransformed variables. This is often impractical / requires a lot of work.
- If you can define your model in terms of the function of the variables, you can directly apply the prior and just work with the transformed variables.
- You can use software that lets you specify such a prior and deals with the rest automatically (well, for non-linear transformations, you may have to figure out the determinant of the Jacobian of the transform). One example is [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/), in which you can e.g. specify something like the following:

  `parameters {
    vector[4] beta;
  }
  model {
    sum(beta) ~ normal(0,1);
    ...`

The last approach is what I would use in practice. The only downside is that it may be hard to understand the implied prior on the original parameters, but to explore that, you can sample without data (and look at the resulting prior on the parameters, as well as the prior predictive distribution).

As a side remark, this is also very useful for overparameterized models for introducing additional (soft) constraints. E.g. if you have a categorical outcome and 3 parameters $\theta_i$ and your model is $Y_j \sim \text{Categorical}(\text{softmax}(\boldsymbol{\theta}))$, then the $\theta_i$ are only identifiable up to a constant. That actually tends to result in sampling problems, that you can get rid off in this manner.

Comment: Implied prior on the $\theta$ parameters are not important, since there may be infinitely many such priors satisfying the prior on the function (due to many to one relation), no?

Comment: @cagdas-ozgenc, yes, in that case it is more a computational trick. That's why I did called that a side remark, but it is actually the #1 reason why I have in the past put priors on transformed parameters. The advantage of this vs. parameterizing the model with fewer parameters (e.g. by defining $\theta_3 := 0$), is that it remains easy to put desired priors on the $\theta_i$ (hard otherwise). It does, of course, affect the final values of the $\theta_i$ (but not of the probabilities for each category - as you say, because the $\theta_i$ are only identified up to an additive constant).

Comment: Could you please write some simple bayesian update expressions. You may choose whatever distribution you like. I am confused on how to even write such priors and combine them with likelihoods.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, I don't know weither this approach has a name ; expect maybe those of *change-of-variable*.

Indeed, by defining a prior on $g(\theta)$, you are simply defining a prior on $\theta$ (assuming $g$ is monotonic, or bijective in multidimensional setting).

More formally, using [change of variable relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar) gives:
$$
p(\theta|y)  \propto p(y|\theta) \cdot p_{\theta}(\theta) \\
\propto  p(y|\theta) \cdot p_{\theta}(g^{-1}(\mu)) \\
\propto  p(y|g^{-1}(\mu)) \cdot p_{\mu}(\mu) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}(g^{-1}(\mu))
$$

As you can see, the equivalence between the two formulations (one in $\theta$ and one in $\mu$) involves a third term that must be accounted for to pass from one formulation to another.

Finally, consider two points : first, if $g$ is not bijective, the inverse function is not defined and thus you have no way to go back from $\mu$ to $\theta$. Second, regarding your initial formulation -that included the regressors $X$- all I wrote above is still consistent if your replace $\theta$ by $\theta^{'}=[\theta,X]$.

Comment: g is almost never monotonic because $\theta$ is usually vector valued such as many parameters in a regression problem.

Comment: Don't forget that X also can be random. Your answer is not relevant at the moment.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc You want your prior to depend on the observation ? Do you agree that this at least answers your comment question  ""can I put a prior on μ^2 instead of directly on μ? How?""

Comment: These days people are even directly regularizing posteriors in variational Bayes, so what I am asking shouldn't be as shocking as you suggest.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc. Sorry if my question was confusing ; I am not choked by your point. I am trying to understand your motivation as best as possible, so that I can try to address your question.

Comment: Actually $x$ are you independent variable, is it ? so they are not your observation. If it is the case, I think this makes no difference just consider the same formulation with $\theta^{'}=[\theta,X]$ instead of $\theta$. What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 1):

#### When you can not compute a posterior for $\mu$ because of missing information in the likelihood

Below is a counterexample for a case where the likelihood function $p(y\vert \mu)$ is not uniquely defined by $\mu$, but depends in a more complex way on the vector $\theta$.

---

Say you have the likelihoodfunction:

$$Y \vert \theta_1+\theta_2 \sim N(\theta_1+\theta_2,1) \quad \text{with} \quad\theta_1 + \theta_2 \sim N(0,1)$$

Now this is like

$$Y \vert \mu \sim N(\mu,1) \quad \text{with} \quad\mu_{prior} \sim N(0,1)$$

and after observing value $Y$ the posterior becomes:

$$\mu_{posterior \vert Y} \sim N(1/2 Y,1/2)$$

---

In the above you can factor out the different $\theta$ from the likelihood function in a single function $\pi (X,\theta_1, ... , \theta_n) = \pi^\prime(g (X, \theta_1, ... , \theta_n)) = \pi ^\prime(\mu)$. That works fine. But say we have now instead some more complicated likelihood function:

$$Y \vert \theta_1+\theta_2 \sim N(\theta_1+\theta_2,\theta_1^2) \quad \text{with} \quad\theta_1 + \theta_2 \sim N(0,1)$$

Now this is like

$$Y \vert \mu, \theta_1 \sim N(\mu,\theta_1) \quad \text{with} \quad\mu_{prior} \sim N(0,1)$$

Which includes an extra (meta-)parameter $\theta_1$ in the likelihood function and we can not (independent from that meta-parameter) express $\mathbb{P}(Y,\mu)$ from which we could compute the posterior for $\mu$.

After observing a value $Y$ the posterior for $\mu$ becomes*:

$$\mu_{posterior \vert Y} \sim N( cY,d)$$ with $c = \frac{1}{\theta_1^2+1}$ and $d = \frac{\theta_1^2}{\theta_1^2+1}$

So you can not solve the posterior of $\mu$ for that problem because you have this metaparameter on which it depends as well.

#### When you can not compute $\theta$ based on $\mu$

This problem is a bit like [Is it possible to derive joint probabilities from marginals with assumptions about the conditionals?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363306/) Your distribution for $\mu=g(\theta)$ is turning a joint distribution for multiple variables (if $\theta$ is a vector) into a distribution for a single variable (some 'sort' of marginal distribution). You can not invert this

Say in the first example above. You might be able to find the distribution for $\mu = \theta_1 + \theta_2$ like $$\mu_{posterior \vert Y} \sim N(1/2 Y,1/2)$$ But it is not possible to turn this into a joint distribution for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ without more information.

---

**This can be derived by the joint distribution $f(y,\mu\vert \theta_1) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \theta_1} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{\theta_1^2}+ \mu^2\right)}$*

Comment: The problem I have with this nice example is that you made sure that $\theta$ is not identifiable. This is like running a regression with 2 independent variables which are perfectly correlated. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc it is a counterexample (and I believe that it is not very unreasonable). It means that *in general* the method is not sufficient to solve the problem, and you may need more information.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc maybe, if you have some more precise sketch of the problem then it may become more clear why this alternative prior might be a good idea. But I do not see it working and I do not get an idea of a good practical case where it would be applied (but I am more theorist and do not know all about practice or have no practice with it). Anyway, even if there might be practical cases where it turns out to be useful, at least there are some weak points in the method.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc It is an example where you need a prior $\pi (\theta_1,\theta_2) $ (or two marginal ones and assume indepemdence) and can not replace it with a prior $\pi (\mu) $

Comment: What I am saying is that you didn’t really need a $\theta_1 + \theta_2 \sim N(0,1)$ for it to fail. Just putting a parameter for variance where you didn’t provide a prior would be the same.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc yes, that's the same. And it is the point of my answer. You can't use $\pi (\mu) $ because it creates such hyperparameters. If you have a likelihood based on the $\theta$ then you need priors for the $\theta $ and can't do away with (only) some grouped prior on $\mu $.

Comment: So far what I understood from your answer is not towards negative but towards positive. Now I realize what I was describing was a hierarchical model with hyperparameters to be determined by empirical bayes, which is something done all the time.